# Intermittent fault with engine start inhibitor on Citröen C3

Tags: starting, citroen

I have a Citroen C3 Exclusive semi-automatic.  The problem is that you need to put some pressure on the brake pedal before you can start the engine.

I have just had home start who didn't listen to a thing I said but all of a sudden it started. I had had enough by then and said thanks and cheerio.  I drove to my destination, not switching off until I returned home.

When I did switch off - yes you've guessed it - it would not start. I know there is a switch somewhere but don't know where. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 2):

It is probably the same switch that is used to light your brake lights.  Get someone to check if your brake lights are lighting up each time you press the brakes.

The switch will more than likely be located just above the brake pedal.

You usually also need to select neutral on the gear selector to disable the inhibitor.

Comment: Man thanks, good information, I will get a friend to have a look for me